# Strange artifacts during camera transition when rendering movie

Tags: rendering, file-format, video

I'm rendering a movie from a series of PNGs with the video sequence editor and the H.264 codec. When the camera changes from the static position to moving there is a strange jitter artifact (see video).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzKe3AZGZG4 (Need to watch in 1080p to clearly see it)

This doesn't show up in the PNGs. Increasing the bitrate doesn't seem to help. I'm not really sure what the other encoding settings do. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you could try to change the GOP Size (Keyframe interval). Try to set it so that a keyframe is set when the movement starts.

Comment: Thanks, that does work! The complete animation is quite long however so as a GOP size I used factor that didn't leave a remainder of the offending keyframe. This does present a problem for the future, what to do if there are multiple places where it occurs?

Comment: I'd like to see the rest. That looks like quality work.

Comment: @David I posted as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the motion wasn't estimated correctly. As a workaround you could try to set the GOP Size (Keyframe interval) so that a keyframe is set when the movement starts.

This seems like an encoder/Blender bug. If such errors occurred at multiple times you could encode with a lossless video format and use one of the many third party video converters as a second step. Possibly with multipass encoding enabled.